# Failed to code sign

Tags: ios, xcode

I am currently developing an IOS APP on Xcode and I want to have a run on my iphone. It says failed to code sign "my app", no valid signing identities (i.e. certificate and private key pair) matching the team ID “(null)” were found.

Xcode can attempt to fix this issue.  Anyone have ideas? Thanks alot!

Comment: Do you have a paid developer program?

Comment: No, I don't have one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For you to run applications build from Xcode that are not submitted to the AppStore, you must have a subscription to a [Developer Program](https://developer.apple.com/membercenter/index.action). This subscriptions is currently $99/year. Not a terrible price to pay but check out [this link](http://forums.macrumors.com/threads/99-ios-developer-program-is-it-worth-it-for-me-to-sign-up.1370559/) to see if it's worth paying for.

Briefly some of the benefits:

1. Code signing to install apps on your own device.
2. Sending builds to websites like [HockeyApp](http://hockeyapp.net/features/) to allow others to test your app and give back feedback
3. Submitting to the Apple AppStore

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Welcome :) glad it was help